# Likelihood an employee gets a failing evaluation by chance

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a group of $n$ employees. Each one is expected to perform a certain task, and the result of this task is either Pass or Fail. As a part of their reviews, I have to tally up their totals, and each employee should have > 80% passing results.

But suppose there is an unknown (but constant) chance that the task fails completely out of the employee's control. Based on the number of passing and failing results of each employee, how can I assess the likelihood that the outcome was just by chance, and not because a certain employee is underperforming?

For example, I have 12 employees, each with 40 attempts. One has a 100% passing rate, while the lowest is an 80% passing rate.

Comment: Do you have any data of tasks that fail completely out of the employees' control?

Comment: @Amir No. But even if we just picked a number, like 10% of the time a failure was not their fault, is this possible to calculate?

Comment: For the case that 10% is given, the problem is more simple. I will add answers for both cases whether 10% is given or not.